# WP Как выводить комментарии в обратном порядке с пагинацией?

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

Есть необходимость реализовать кнопку переключения, что б при её нажатии коментарии которые показывались к посту, с пагинацией (от старых к новым) после её нажатия отображались от новых к старым (с той же пагинацией). Вот в документации, к [wp_list_comments()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_comments#reverse_top_level) есть описание к параметру 'reverse_top_level' который за то отвечает.
Но в моём случаии что-то идет не так. Вот мой код

```
<?php if (post_password_required()) {
    return;
}
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$per_page = 4;
$comments_count = get_comments_number($post_id);


if (isset($_GET['cpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['cpage'])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['cpage'];
}
$page = max(1, $page);

if ($GET_value_filter == 'newest') { /// В этом параметре я с GET параметра страницы забираю, что это сортировка от новых комментариев к старым.
           
            function custom_default_comments_page2($value)
            {
                return 'newest';
            }

            add_filter('pre_option_default_comments_page', 'custom_default_comments_page2');

            $arg = array(
                'type' => 'comment',
                'reverse_top_level' => 1,
                'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
                'per_page' => $per_page,
                'number' => $per_page,
                'cpage' => $page,
            );
            

            wp_list_comments($arg);
   
        }
```

Тут возникает 2 ошибки.

1. Я 'per_page' => 4, ожидаю, что на первой странице комментариев мне отобразиться 4 комментария. А мне почему-то показывает только 2.
   *Тут надо уточнить, что при выводе комментариев от старых->новым это действительно последняя страница с 2-м комментариями. Но тут то в первой странице должно быть 4 коммента.
2. Последняя страница пагинации содержит тот же набор комментариев что и первая, в независимости от того по сколько комментариев выводить на страницу...

Может кто-то, что-то полезное сказать, по поводу данной проблемы ? Может кто-то может посоветовать как продебажить данную функцию и понимать, что именно риходит по странично в `wp_list_comments` ?

---

Вот создал тестовый вариант в `Sandbox`

https://realvisitor.s2-tastewp.com/hello-world/

Доступы к админке

https://realvisitor.s2-tastewp.com/wp-admin/

Имя пользователя: blackstar1991

Пароль: Lm_AOAX9ILs

Через плагин `WP File Manager` можна править код

`twentytwentyone/template-parts/custom-comments-template.php`

Comment: Похоже на баг в ядре. Порядок и разбивку на страницы можно указать в админке. Но результат со стандартной темой будет с описанными проблемами...

Comment: А как решать? Есть какие советы, вроде ж примитивная задача, а в тупик ставит...

Comment: Да как решать - xdebug и вперед... Или самому писать вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр 'reverse_top_level' в wp_list_comments() инвертирует порядок отображения комментариев верхнего уровня, но не изменяет порядок отображения ответов на комментарии. Это означает, что если вы устанавливаете 'reverse_top_level' в 1, то комментарии верхнего уровня будут отображаться от новых к старым, но ответы на них будут отображаться от старых к новым.

Вам нужно изменить порядок сортировки ответов на комментарии от новых к старым. Для этого можно использовать параметр type в массиве аргументов, передаваемых в
wp_list_comments()

```
$arg = array(
    'type' => 'comment',
    'reverse_top_level' => 1,
    'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
    'per_page' => $per_page,
    'number' => $per_page,
    'cpage' => $page,
    'page' => $page,
    'order' => 'ASC', // Установите порядок сортировки ответов на комментарии как ASC (от новых к старым)
);

wp_list_comments($arg);
```

Этот код изменит порядок сортировки ответов на комментарии, чтобы они отображались от новых к старым. После этого ваша пагинация должна работать правильно, и на первой странице отобразятся 4 комментария верхнего уровня, а также ответы на них от новых к старым.

Comment: К сожалению, данный код выдает совершенно непонятные комментарии. (Они не свежие, а старые -1 страница ) Хотя если с него убрать про `'page' => $page,` то выдает то же что и в моем примере, но почему-то на первой странице не $per_page комментариев, а остаток от новых.  Ну и на следующих страницах пагинации комментарии отображаться в порядке от старых к новым.

Comment: К сожалению, второй вариант тоже не работает. Я развернул тестовый сайт (дополнил задачу), может вы сможете показать, как реализовать обратное отображения комментарие. Файл  `custom-comments-template.php`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$per_page = 4;
$paged = get_query_var('cpage') ? get_query_var('cpage') : 1;

$arg = array(
    'type' => 'comment',
    'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
    'per_page' => $per_page,
    'page' => $paged,
    'reverse_top_level' => ($paged === 1) ? 1 : 0, // Инвертируем порядок на 
первой странице
);

wp_list_comments($arg);
```

Будет менять порядок сортировки верхнего уровня только на первой странице, чтобы отображать их от новых к старым. На последующих страницах порядок остается стандартным.

Comment: Не надо плодить ответы. Вносите правки или дополнения в первый ответ.